# what should i set the "external_url" for gitlab server in ubuntu on my desktop

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I'm trying to install gitlab server on ubuntu 18.04. 
But now i need to setup the external_url so as to run the gitlab on my system.
I want to run the gitlab server on my local network. How to go about this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Configuring the external URL for GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html#configuring-the-external-url-for-gitlab)

As stated, simply set it to the URL that you will be using from your browser to connect to it. It is only used for generating absolute links.